# Why is there another _ga_ cookie in my site with unknown ID?

Tags: google-analytics, cookie, google-analytics-4

I open my site, open devtool and navigate to the Cookies section in Storage tab. I see that there are three `_ga_` cookies: `_ga`, `_ga_XXXXXX1` and `_ga_XXXXXX2`. `XXXXXX1` is indeed my measurement ID, but I can't recognize `XXXXXX2`. Both of them has the same values for almost every field, including created, last accessed and expired times. The only values that they are very slightly different are its `Value` and `Size`:

|  | `Value` | `Size` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `_ga_XXXXXX1` | GS1.1.1697276879.1.1.1697277042.58.0.0 | 52 |
| `_ga_XXXXXX2` | GS1.1.1697276879.1.1.1697277042.0.0.0 | 51 |

How to identify where `_ga_XXXXXX2` comes from?

Comment: I'll comment and Upvote the question since I have the same interogation at the moment. I have an unknow Google Tag Manager ID that is imported in the DOM of my website and I would like to know from where it comes. I already have disabled wordpress plugins to test if the ID would leave but still there.